# Angular 17 - Difficulties Implementing Corporate Proxy

Tags: angular, proxy, angular17

The team I work in manages Angular web apps and mobile apps. Our apps are built using various versions of Angular, with our latest apps using Angular 16. I've been testing Angular 17 over the last few weeks, but I'm having difficulty getting the corporate proxy to work using HttpsProxyAgent.

Until now, we used the following CommonJS structure for our proxy file (proxy.config.dev.js). Looking at old articles on Angular, this format was common a few years ago.

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const proxy = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY || 'http://ourcompanyproxy.com';

const config = [
    {
        context: '/URL1',
        target: 'https://targeturl1.com',
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/URL1": ""
        },
        secure: false
    },
{
        context: '/URL2',
        target: 'https://targeturl2.com',
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/URL2": ""
        },
        secure: false
    }
];

function setupForCorporateProxy() {
    if (proxy) {
        console.log('Using corporate proxy DEVELOPMENT server: ' + proxy);
        config.forEach(function (entry) {
            entry.agent = HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);
        });
    }
    return config;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy();
```

Unfortunately, this format throws errors in Visual Studio Code, so I have attempted to use the format that is recommended by Angular.

*"type": "module"* was added to package.json in order for this format to work correctly.

```
import HttpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent';

const proxy = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY || 'http://ourcompanyproxy.com';

const config = [
    {
        context: '/URL1',
        target: 'https://targeturl1.com',
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/URL1": ""
        },
        secure: false
    },
{
        context: '/URL2',
        target: 'https://targeturl2.com',
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/URL2": ""
        },
        secure: false
    }
];

export default (proxyConfig) => {
    if (proxy) {
        console.log('Using corporate proxy DEVELOPMENT server: ' + proxy);
        for (const entry of config) {
            entry.agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);
          }
    }
    return proxyConfig;
}
```

No errors arise using this format in Visual Studio Code, but I'm unable to hit my target URL.

The Angular 17 version of our application does load correctly, but data is not loading. Chrome shows a 200 ok response, but the preview shows the app's 404 page and the end point is never hit. In other words, the response is the HTML for the app's 404 page instead of the expected data array.

The error shown is:

> "Http failure during parsing for localhost"

SSR is enabled for this project, but at this stage I believe this is a proxy issue.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.
Kevin

Comment: Unfotunately, StackOverflow marked the question as Spam when I attempted to include some references etc.

For clarification, the proxy format I followed can be found at https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy

The full parsing error that was returned contains the following

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at _FetchBackend.parseBody (http://localhost:4200/@fs/C:/myapp/myapp%20-%20Angular%2017/.angular/cache/17.0.7/vite/deps/chunk-ZQHGFRLU.js?v=923e642b:1175:42)...

Comment: As of Node version 17, Node will not always resolve http://localhost:<port> to http://127.0.0.1:<port> depending on each machine's configuration. You can fix this issue by updating the target from http://localhost:<port> to http://127.0.0.1:<port>.

Comment: Thanks for responding D A. Just to clarify, there are no issues loading the app locally and I'm not seeing any ECONNREFUSED errors. Pages with no API calls are loading correctly. The target URL is a CastIron link so there's no reference to localhost on the page.

Answer (score 0):

l had a similar issue when trying the new esbuild based build:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
```

so i just brought back the old one

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Achraf. I was on annual leave when you posted this so just seeing this now :)

I did many tests on this two weeks ago and the issue now appears to be resolved. I did not change any code, but updating to the latest version of the Angular core resolved the issue.

I suspect the earlier versions of Angular 17 had a bug that has since been addressed.